# Read only file system when changing computer

Tags: filesystem, ssd, read-only

I have a dual bay SATA docking station with a single ssd, connected to my server, through usb 3.0. This all works fine.

However when I connect the usb of the docking station into another server I cannot make or change files as it is saying "Read only file system".

When connecting it back to the original server it works as expected and I can store/change files.

Is it possible to use this over different servers, with the usb?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using "Remove safely" or the umount, sync, and power-off functions before yanking the USB cable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed issue by installing ntfs-3g and executing ntfsfix

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
sudo ntfsfix -d /dev/sd..
```